# display and remove all chars > ascii code 127

Tags: windows, regex

How can I display and remove all chars > ascii code 127 from a file?

file is unicode 16bit

UPDATE
Dennis has solved it but there is some interesting discussion about number ranges.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @gravvity why do you ask?

Comment: Because it makes a difference in how you go about it. An additional question: Do you have Unix-style tools available through Cygwin or GNUWin32 or similar?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson I'm open to many options of going about it. I have both Cygwin and Gnuwin32, it'd be nice to do it via those but a problem with that is my file is unicode 16bit. I notice that the line:  cat | od -c  interprets \0s between each char, and grep doesn't work on it cos the letters abc as seen by grep are not contiguous for presumably the same reason. they assume 8-bit per char.

Comment: Since you have a Unicode file, you should know that's the real reason grawity and I asked for additional information. Removing bytes with byte values (notice that I didn't say "characters" and "ASCII codes") from a Unicode file will give weird results. What is it that you're *really* trying to do?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson -that- What you just said. But It will only give weird results if one doesn't understand the structure of a unicode file, and neither of us are idiots with computers, especially not you. So it needn't give weird results. Assume 16-bit little endian. Here is an example. From notepad. This file reads abc\r\ndef  Here goes- feff 0061 0062 0063 000d 000a 0064 0065 0066 000d 000a    Notice the structure is it starts with FEFF so we leave that. There may be \xDA or \uFEFF  or all manner of things I don't want > \x7F within the contents of the file. I don't expect anything >\uFFFF

Comment: @Dennis Williamson  I don't really want something written in C or equivalent lines of high level programming language code. It'd be nice if gnuwin32 tools could handle it. anybody suggesting text editors that can that's good too.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson  \x7F = \u007F  I think you understand what I mean. If I got my technical notation wrong then please correct me.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson  it'd be nice to have a solution that works for big endian  as well as [a solution for] little endian.

Comment: the endianess isn't an issue 'cos I could amend the regex.. I made an error in my comment 'cos it seems od reads it not in address order, I think it shows the high order address byte then the low order address byte(not sure about terminology).  xxd shows it in address order. big endian is feff00610061  little endian  fffe61006100

Comment: The solution is flexible enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to take would be to convert the file to hex digits, remove the digit patterns that you don't want, then convert back.

```
$ echo 'A Unicode character: [ñ]' | xxd -p | sed 's/c3b1//' | xxd -r -p
A Unicode character: []
```

You could use AWK or any other text manipulation technique in place of `sed`. Be careful of ambiguous sequences.

Let me know if this approaches what you have in mind.

Comment: yep, that is approaching what I have in mind

Comment: from there I can see how i'd probably do it..  od -x myfile | cut to get past FEFF at the start of it  , capture pairs in the regex within my hex range, in sed.

Comment: actually, my cut idea wouldn't cut it.. but yes the idea of a program or set that could let me see the hex, work with regex on the hex and write it back is one general approach I had in mind.. i'd be interested to see how you tweak it to the requirements. You are welcome to post other sketches of approaches if anything springs to mind..if it's not too much trouble. i'd be interested and I think it'd be useful.

Comment: i'm actually getting there via that sketch you gave, and using cut , i missed a tr -d '\n' before it..

Comment: actually i'm stuck trying to tweak your sketch . your sketch is fine (of course as you know!) but my tweaking is the problem. 'cos i know that after | tr -d '\n' and then  cut 5-, which works, I don't want to just scan for say FEFF or [8-F][0-F][0-F][0-F] because I don't want to overlap bytes from 2 chars.  And whatever I put in the find section of sed s goes. So if I try to match every byte pair then it'd delete the lot. and i'm not sure how or if it's possible with sed to replace byte pairs conditionally.

Comment: @barlop: `sed` can do the job that you have `cut` doing. `sed 's/^.\{4\}//; s/...`. It could put the BOM back when you're done, too. Trying to make `sed` keep from overlapping could be done, but it'd get unwieldy fast. AWK would be better suited to the task. This really looks like a job for Python or Perl, which are better suited to binary data (no `od` or `xxd` needed) and probably have libraries that would do what you want. They would probably automatically handle the endianess based on the BOM.

Comment: I see a way.  I could do it in steps. Putting a space(would be 1 byte I suppose, with sed! ;-) ), between each 4 nibbles/hex digits. Then scanning works without overlap with every contiguous sequence of hex digits belonging to a char. of course would then remove the space afterwards and write the file w/ xxd like your sketch.

Comment: while I can't demonstrate with echo 'cos echo in cygwin or gnuwin32 doesn't dump unicode. But i've worked out a solution based on your sketch and my spaces idea:  a.q being the input file $ xxd -p a.q | tr -d '\n' | sed "s/\([0-9a-f]\{4\}\)/\1 /g" | sed -r "s/([0
][0][8-9a-f][0-9a-f])|([1-9a-f][1-9a-f][8-9a-f][0-9a-f])//g" | tr -d ' ' | sed
"s/\(.*\)/feff\1/" | xxd -r -p >a.q2    Are there any tweaks you'd do? I did once find some months ago that sed -e "..." -e "..." didn't work right dunno why but sed "s/.." | sed "s/.." did so I guess they're not the same.

Comment: that thing i did works btw just maybe a bit inefficient too many pipes or something.

Comment: @barlop: It looks like there's a stray space after a zero in your second `sed` command. I don't know why you're having trouble with `-e`; `sed '...;...` and `sed -e '...' -e '...'` both work for me. In fact the latter form is more likely to be the more portable of the two. Of course `sed | sed` works and is also portable. It's just inefficient. Also, `sed 's/ //g` will do the job of the second `tr` and, if you can get multiple commands to work, it can be incorporated into the `sed` commands which then could all be combined into one. *`If.`* Then, there's always Python or Perl...

Comment: @barlop: There are gaps in your number sequence. If you are deleting 16-bit words greater than 0x007F then shouldn't 0x01FF be deleted? It's the beginning of the first of many such gaps. Your regex should presumably cover 2^16 - 2^7 (65408) values and instead it only covers 28928. Try: `00[8-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[0-9a-f][1-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[1-9a-f]0[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]` (note the removal of parentheses and some brackets, too). Have you considered `iconv -c --from-code UTF-16 --to-code US-ASCII --output outputfile inputfile`?

Comment: What does the "If"  you wrote in italics mean?   (did you just mean if I can get the -e".." to work?).   I agree it should cover 2^16-2^7. You fixed it. Impressive you got exactly how many values my regex matched..   Did you find that via test code or flawless logic? I will look into iconv

Comment: @barlop: I meant to emphasize the "if", since eliminating the `tr` is pointless if the `sed` commands have to be separate anyway. That would mean the `tr` would be mootly (new word) replaced by a separate `sed` command. Of course it was flawless logic! ;) (I lie: it was test code, but I did immediately spot that is was flawed - mostly because that kind of regex that attempts to do range-checking usually is). I'm writing a little script to automate the analysis I did. I will post a self-answered question when I get it finished.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson don't worry about the testing code if it's too much work.. What was the thinking behind the way you worked out your number range regex though?  If you see my question's update, I managed to work one out thinking in terms of each section between |  |  matching a range, each range going on from the next. I ended up with 3 ranges, but a different regex to you. So i'm curious what your thinking was behind that aspect of your solution.

Comment: @barlop: I just looked at where the gaps were and chose something that would fill them. Your new regex is much better since it's more systematic and, well, *regular*. I think the utility that I'm working on will be useful to myself and others and will be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at this question

It looks I used one of these lines in the end

(seems to be dennis's regex)

```
$ xxd -p a.q | tr -d '\n' | sed "s/([0-9a-f]\{4\})/\1 /g" | sed -r "s/(00[8-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[0-9a-f][1-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|[1-9a-f]0[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])//g" | tr -d ' ' | sed "s/(.*)/feff\1/" | xxd -r -p >a.q2
```

or this (seems to be my regex)

```
$ xxd -p a.q | tr -d '\n' | sed "s/([0-9a-f]\{4\})/\1 /g" | sed -r "s/(00[89A-F][0-9A-F]|0[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{2}|[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{3})//g" | tr -d ' ' | sed "s/(.*)/feff\1/" | xxd -r -p >a.q2
```

this is some commentary on how I worked it out, with a few tests.

```
0080-00FF     00[89A-F][0-9A-F]
0100-0FFF     0[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{2}
1000-FFFF     [1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{3}
```

and here are some tests that shows that regex works. I had put them into my question when I solved it but I should have put them into an answer.

Total Hex Chars 85

```
$ xxd -u -p a.aa.txt | sed -r "s/.{4}/\0 /g" | grep -oE "[0-9A-F]{4}" | wc -l
85
```

Total that I want, 72

```
$ xxd -u -p a.aa.txt | sed -r "s/.{4}/\0 /g" | grep -oE "00[0-7][0-F]" | wc -
l
72
```

Total that I don't want, 13

```
$ xxd -p -u a.aa.txt | sed -r "s/[0-9A-F]{4}/\0 /g" | grep -oP '((?!00[0-7][0-9A-F])(?=[^ ]).){4}' | wc -l
13
```

Total that I don't want, 13

```
$ xxd -u -p a.aa.txt | sed -r "s/.{4}/\0 /g" | grep -oE "00[89A-F][0-9A-F]|0[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{2}|[1-9A-F][0-9A-F]{3}" | wc –l
13
```

Comment: and looking at it now i'm wondering why I didn't just grep the unicode hex characters I wanted to keep as in this test `$ xxd -u -p a.aa.txt | sed -r "s/.{4}/\0 /g" | grep -oE "00[0-7][0-F]"`    Rather than replacing the ones I didn't want to keep with nothing. (the latter amounts to a much longer regex)

Comment: by the way, the first xxd -p a.q line uses the regex in dennis's comment, the second uses the regex that I came up with.